# Display field value from custom object inside visual force page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I have a custom object called *Portal* that has a custom field in it called URL.

I also created a visual force page that displays an iframe. This page is displayed in my *Portal* as a child. I need to take the custom field, URL, from my parent object and display it as the src in my visual force page.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Portal__c" sidebar="false">
   <apex:iframe src="{!URL}"/>
</apex:page>
```

This is not working. I am getting this error:

> Error: Unknown property 'Portal__cStandardController.URL'

Am I going about this the right way? Any help would be appreciated. This is my first time working with SalesForce and I am only working within the GUI. Answers in layman's terms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This should work : 

<apex:page StandardController="Portal__c" sidebar="false">
   <apex:iframe src="{!Portal__c.URL__c}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Remember Custom field's always have "__c" in end.
Always use proper API Namess